# Не рабоает wrap_content в GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Не выходит нормально отображать изображения в GridLayoutManager. wrap_content не работает. Изображения выводит Universal Image Loader.

Есть несколько вариантов вывода изображений 6, 7 или 8 изображений.

Например для 8 изображений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под GridLayoutManager много пустого места. Я пробовал [это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681394/recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-trying-to-solve-wrap-content)
Но результат тотже. Даже не знаю, что еще попробовать.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/sharedGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"        
    local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@id/expandTextView" />
```

Конфиг для Universal Image Loader

```
 var options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                            .ShowImageOnLoading(Resource.Drawable.shared_gray_empty_photo)
                            .ResetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                            .ConsiderExifParams(true)
                            .CacheInMemory(false)
                            .CacheOnDisk(true)
                            .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

В версии 23.2.0 все отлично работает, в версиях выше какая-то чушь началась. Замените строку на вот эту

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

Comment: Спасибо работает(если медленно скролить), но не достаточно хорошо, если я быстро скролю, то высота RecyclerView больше или меньше,  чем высота фотографий - высчитывает неверно. Что еще можно сделать или попробовать?

Comment: А вот это уже не знаю..